# Failed to execute goal org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am getting a strange error here, maven is not working with sudo.

when i executed `mvn clean install -DskipTests`
i got this error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.8:invoke (default) on project http: Execution default of goal org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.8:invoke failed: Plugin org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.8 -> org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:jar:2.13: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:jar:2.13: Could not transfer artifact org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:pom:2.13 from/to gradle (http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local/): Access denied to: http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local/org/gradle/gradle-tooling-api/2.13/gradle-tooling-api-2.13.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

so then i tried `sudo mvn clean install -DskipTests`

and strangly i got this error :

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

after executing `mvn -v`

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /home/akshay/java/jdk1.8.0_251/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.3.0-45-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

and if executed with sudo `sudo mvn -v`

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

my env variables :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/akshay/java/jdk1.8.0_251
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Quick tip, whenever you need to run maven with sudo, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update the mirror. Here is the snippet from [developpaper.com](https://developpaper.com/replacing-maven-image-with-alibaba-cloud-central-warehouse-to-improve-download-speed/):

- Open the configuration file of Maven (the windows machine is generally in `conf` / `settings.xml` of the Maven installation directory). In the `<mirrors></mirrors>`. Add mirror child node in the tag:

  ```
  <mirror>
      <id>aliyunmaven</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      < name > Alibaba cloud public warehouse < / name >
      <url>https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public</url>
  </mirror>
  ```
- Modifying `pom.xml` in the configuration mode of a single project:

  ```
   <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>alimaven</id>
          <name>aliyun maven</name>
          <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
          </repository>
  </repositories>
  ```

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/2343)

[Additional link](https://laptrinhx.com/maven-replacement-central-warehouse-aliyun-2549426160/)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` isn't going to help you with a missing dependency.  That's what you've got going on there.

Going to paste a line-wrapped version of that same error you've got here.

```
Execution default of goal org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.8:invoke failed: 
    Plugin org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
    Failed to collect dependencies at org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.8 -> org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:jar:2.13: 
    Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:jar:2.13: 
    Could not transfer artifact org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:pom:2.13 from/to gradle (http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local/): 
    Access denied to: http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local/org/gradle/gradle-tooling-api/2.13/gradle-tooling-api-2.13.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
```

So whatever configuration you've got is pointing to a path that doesn't exist at http://repo.gradle.org, which I don't think is where you want to be.

Comment: ...Don't use `sudo` for this.  The root user does not have a need to execute any Maven goals on your machine, nor should you let it.  Troubleshooting why `sudo` doesn't work when you run `mvn` is like trying to figure out why your AC isn't running when your car is clearly out of gas.